# multiple files but same url which is index.php

Tags: php, hyperlink

hello guys i badly need your help, php noob here,

im creating a bulletin board-like calendar and it shows the different entries each month. the calendar is divided into 4 quarters hence, i have a php file per quarter. each file displays the months for that quarter and their respective entries. example; my firstq.php contains entries for january, february and march.

i dont have a submit button in any of the page, just a drop down linked image of 1Q, 2Q, 3Q, 4Q that redirects to each file.

how could i declare that when i click the 1Q image it would display the file firstq.php but the url is still index.php and so on?

my default index.php shows 3rd quarter since its july now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a parameter to the url that determines which page you're on.

```
<?php

// at the top of the page

$quarters = array('Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4');
$quarter = 'Q1';

// don't allow access to any file on your system
if( isset($_GET['quarter']) && in_array($_GET['quarter'], $quarters) ) {
  $quarter = $_GET['quarter'];
}

// switch the short syntax to a filename
switch($quarter) {
  case 'Q1' :
    $quarter = 'firstq.php';
  break;
  case 'Q2' :
    $quarter = 'secondq.php';
  break;
  case 'Q3' :
    $quarter = 'thirdq.php';
  break;
  case 'Q4' :
    $quarter = 'fourthq.php';
  break;
}
```

And then this in the page where you are ready to include it.

```
<?php include_once $quarter; ?>
```

---

Your links to each quarter would look like this.

```
<ul id="quarters">
  <li><a href="index.php?quarter=Q1"><img src="images/Q1.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="index.php?quarter=Q2"><img src="images/Q2.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="index.php?quarter=Q3"><img src="images/Q3.jpg" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="index.php?quarter=Q4"><img src="images/Q4.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: so im guessing this is on the index.php page?

Comment: @jet yes, this would be part of the code that goes on `index.php`.

Comment: how would it affect these?

<li><a href="firstq2012.php"><img src="images/1Q.jpg" width="74" height="35" /></a><ul>
                 <li><a href="secondq2012.php"><img src="images/2Q.jpg" width="74" height="35" /></a><ul>
                 <li><a href="index.php"><img src="images/3Q.jpg" width="74" height="35" /></a><ul>
                 <li><a href="fourthq2012.php"><img src="images/4Q.jpg" width="74" height="35" /></a><ul>

Comment: <?php include_once $quarter; ?>

- is this also in the index.php?

Comment: @jet yes, that will include the file into your page. You will want to add that where you want the content to show up.

Comment: it worked! thank you sir. i have another question, how do you validate and sanitize the url so it wont accept invalid characters? because if i edit the url it still enters the index.php page.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass on a POST/GET parameter to the index page like this:

```
"index.php?Quarter=Q1"
```

You would still land on the index.php, you only need to add the logic to handle the value of Quarter.

Comment: i have a form less page sir. so im having a hard time on how would i pass a get parameter.

Comment: See the answer below, that's what I ment :) + You could always write some javascript code that would detect the change in selection in the dropbox & send you over to the new site (with &?data=x ofcourse). Be creative, sir ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can have index.php

```
require_once('1Q.php');
```

And then in an if statement, chose which Q.php to call on the next selection.

Comment: The links would look like:

  echo '<a href="http://www.jet.com/index.php?id=1Q">';

Then you would use

 $quarter = $_GET['id'];

to pull the ID out of the URL.

Comment: (Sorry, I kept hitting ENTER and kept posting...)

Answer (score 0):

in index.php

```
<?php
$quarters = array(1=>'firstq', 2=>'secondq', 3=>'thirdq', 4=>'fourthq');
$quarter = isset($_GET['quarter']) ? $_GET['quarter'] : null;

if(isset($quarters[$quarter)
    include $quarters[$_GET['quarter']] . '.php';
```

test like index.php?quarter=3

Or if you only care about the current quarter do this

```
$quarters = array(1=>'firstq', 2=>'secondq', 3=>'thirdq', 4=>'fourthq');
$month = date("m", time()); 
$quarter=  ceil($month/3);

include $quarters[$quarter] . '.php';
```

Comment: what would my links to call each page look like then?

Comment: I have it in my post.  Call the page like index.php?quarter=2

Comment: I have updated my post and added a section to show if you actually only care about the current quarter